# multiple calls to amfphp using singleton pattern on netconnection

Tags: php, actionscript-3, singleton, request, amfphp

I'm trying to call AMFPHP two times on a single ActionScript method and what happen is that only the first call succeed. The second one doesn't return an error, doesn't alerts anything, it is more likely that it doesn't even happens and I'm not sure why.

Here is an example:

```
public function editSomething():void{
    if(dgChild.selectedIndex == -1){
       Alert.show("You need to select a register in order to edit it.");
       return;
    }
    _parent1.getParentByChild(dgChild.selectedItem.id);
    _parent2.getParent2ByChild(dgChild.selectedItem.id);
}
```

When this method is called, the first parent is called normally, but the second one isn't.

The variables _parent1 and _parent2 are Objects that communicates with PHP and holds the result:

```
public class parentDAO{
    //Service or Class that this objectDAO will be communicating with. 
    private const _phpController:String = "parentController/";
    private var _AMFPHP:AMFPHP = AMFPHP.getInstance();

    //ArrayCollection that will be filled with data comming from PHP/Database.        
    [Bindable] private var _dataProviderAeronave:ArrayCollection;
    //I use public getter and setter for this dataProvider

    public function getParentByChild(child_id:int):void{
          _AMFPHP.GATEWAY.call(_phpController + "getParentByChild", new Responder(resultGetParent), child_id);
    }

    private function resultGetParent(result:Array):void{
            dataProviderParent = new ArrayCollection(result); 
    }
}
```

Now, assuming that the variable _parent1 is one object declared above and the _parent2 is another object of an another class very very similarly as this one and assuming that both communication works perfectly fine, the problem arise now: when I call both in one single ActionScript method. If I call just one of them, it will work normally, but when I call two services, the second is never actually called. I'm sure about it because I can see it through Service Capture Proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: _parent1 and _parent2 are different services from the amfphp. Different classes, different tables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that every time that the NetConnection class makes a call to AMFPHP, it automatically closes the connection with the path. So, basically the next call is ignored and I have no idea why it doesn't show up in the Flash Debugger.
My solution was to always check if the Gateway is connected through the "connected" [read-only] attribute in the NetConnection class. if it is false, I force a new connection and voalá, the script works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

any idea how to fix this class? i am having more or less same problem like you amfphp is already busy when trying to communicate but i am using this class extensively.
basically what it do is call ChannelPicker.getInstance().getNewRemoteObject()

```
package communication
{
    import flash.net.NetConnection;

    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
    import mx.managers.BrowserManager;
    import mx.managers.IBrowserManager;
    import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
    import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
    import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

    import spark.components.Label;

    public class ChannelPicker
    {
        private static  var instance:ChannelPicker;
        protected var channelSet:ChannelSet= new ChannelSet();
        protected var url:String;

        static public function getInstance():ChannelPicker{
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new ChannelPicker();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public function ChannelPicker()
        {
            do
            {
                var browser:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
                browser.init("","");
                url = browser.url;
            }while (url == null || url=="");
                        /*oracle_plajva is project name which ends up being html name of my file so to get current url i need to split it */
            url = url.split(/oracle_plajva.html/)[0] + "Amfphp/index.php";
            var chanel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("amfphp", url);
            this.channelSet = new ChannelSet();
            this.channelSet.addChannel(chanel);
        }

        public function getChannelSet():ChannelSet{
            return channelSet;
        }

        public function getNewRemoteObject():RemoteObject{
            var o:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject();
            o.destination = "amfphp";
            o.channelSet = channelSet;
            return o;
        }

        public function getUrl():String{
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how RemoteObject works nor I have experience with it, but it seems like you're factoring new objects to connect with AMFPHP every time you call this getNewremoteObject(). The purpose of my Singleton class was to narrow down the amount of NetConnection objects that I build along the application. You seem to be just trying to centralize where you connect with AMFPHP, right?

Comment: yeah thats right .i can refresh my app as much as i want as long as it is single instance, but if i have 2 instances of flash player and my up running and making calling the amfphp service at same time some wierd things happen and i don't know how to debug it.
same thing happens even if i am using 2 copies of app and amfphp which are the same. so i am thinking it is eaither some wierd caching on flash browser side or on amfphp side. 
anyway here is what happens as you can see in pic something goes wrong
http://tinypic.com/r/i4fei9/6 http://tinypic.com/r/mwcvuv/6

Comment: Any particular reason to use RemoteObject? I can help you a lot more with NetConnection.
About the ScreenShot, I think that the Row_number column comes from a select from Oracle using ROW_NUMBER magic variable. I don't have much experience with Oracle, but I do remember that this is required in order to paginate results. Do you get any error message from Flex or from Apache Log (PHP)?

Comment: With a more attention in the pics, I actually noticed it's two different tables. Why did you mark the ROW_NUMBER column?

Comment: because it should be named # for some reason header text doesn't work i mean if i inspect it with monster debugger both instances have set it right but it isn't. I also tried using charles sniffer to inspect my traffic and amfphp is in both runs running same data so i am guessing it must be something wrong on client side, in other words some wierd flash player bug.